# How to generate unique user ID like Zerodha's user ID with Node.js/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to generate random unique User ID for one of my project and found Zerodha has very easy to remember user ids.

In Zerodha user ID: First two char's are Alphabets and then four char's are numbers.

How to make Id's Like Zerodha: `"AC1940"`,`"AZ9940"`, `"YM1300"` etc.. ?

I wanted them to be unique and easy to remember.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate random alphabets and number from [ASCII code](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) and `Math.random()` function and join them in a string.

```js
const generateCharacter = (base, range) => String.fromCharCode(base + Math.floor(Math.random() * range)),
      userId = Array.from({length: 2}, () => generateCharacter(65, 26)).join('') +
               Array.from({length: 4}, () => generateCharacter(48, 10)).join('');
console.log(userId);
```

Comment: You would also have to ensure that the generated used ID didn't already exist too!

Comment: Nice answer, that's some elegant code @Hassan

Answer (score 1):

You can create a random 6 digit number as

```js
var randomNumber = (min, max) =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

function generateUUID() {
  const alphabets = [0, 1];
  return Array.from({ length: 6 }, (_, i) => {
    return alphabets.includes(i)
      ? String.fromCharCode(randomNumber(65, 90))
      : randomNumber(0, 9);
  }).join("");
}

console.log( generateUUID() );
```

Answer (score 1):

By respect of guys methods, those are not standard ways for unique random id.
one of the standard and best ways to get random and standard methods for that is UUID.

**EDITED:**

you can use this [uuid nodejs package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) to install and get the uuid unique random id corrctly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use deprecated `shortid` npm package or popular `nanoid`. Considering you don't want to get lengthy strings as ID, `uuid` and similar packages are off the table. Surely using methods to create random strings wouldn't accomplish the purpose as we know that random strings are not necessarily unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use urid package `npm install urid`

```
import urid from 'urid';

// generate 6 digit random alpha numeric id
urid(6, 'ALPHANUM'); // QRAK22

// or generate to string and concat
urid(2, 'ALPHA') + urid(4, 'num'); // FD3274
```

You can make any combination, read the full docs here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/urid